# Update deployment labels using “kubectl patch” does not work in v1.18

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to update a label using kubectl v1.18.

I tried kubectl patch deployment my-deployment --patch "$(cat patch1.yaml)"; it returns an error

The Deployment "my-deployment" is invalid: spec.selector: Invalid value: v1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{"app":"nginx"}, MatchExpressions:[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}: field is immutable

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    client: user
  name:  my-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: revproxy
  strategy:
     type: RollingUpdate
     rollingUpdate:
       maxUnavailable: 1
       maxSurge: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: revproxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx:1.7.9
        name: nginx
        resources: {}
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
```

The patch yaml is

```
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#label-selector-updates)

> Note: In API version apps/v1, a Deployment's label selector is
> immutable after it gets created.

Motivations for making label selector immutable are

1. Changing selectors leads to undefined behaviors - users are not expected to change the selectors
2. Having selectors immutable ensures they always match created children, preventing events such as accidental bulk orphaning

If you want to make modification to label selector you will have to delete the exiting deployment and recreate it.

Modification to only `metadata.labels` should work though.

Comment: Yes, `metadata.labels` would work if process wasn't bulk patch. In this case all of changes are aborted if one or more of them are failed.